# Which ecommerce would you recommend to use as a headless ecommerce

Tags: ecommerce, angularjs

I have been researching for two days but I'm not sure about the best option. We want to build a very flexible ecommerce and combine it with other services to extend its functionality. We are currently working with Joomla + Virtuemart and we find many difficulties in to addapting them to our needs. We also want to do a real separattion between back and front so we are looking for headless systems in order to combine them with Angular 5.

**We have the following requisites**

- The site must be multilingual.
- The site must have (or let the ability to develop it) and
  administrator panel.
- The administrator panel must allow a non-developer person to manage
  products, categories... (CRUD).
- The administrator panel must allow a non-developer person to manage
  SEO settings within each product, each category...
- The ecommerce must provide an API to CRUD the information to connect
  it to our ERP, SPAs and other services.
- The ecommerce logic must be configurable. I mean we would like to
  modify checkout logic/steps without doing hacks in core. More
  functionalities would be also required to adapt.

**What I have so far**

I have been reading general docs and oppinions about many ecommerces with API based on different languages. such as PHP (Magento, Prestashop, Sylius, Opencart...), NodeJS (ReactionCommerce, Ymple...), Go (QOR), Django (Oscar), Ruby (Spree). I discarted payment options (Moltin, StoreHippo ...). Then I read API docs and use demo pages so I could filter. Now we have three finalists: Prestashop, Sylius and Aimeos bundle. I have to add that we already have experience with Symfony thus the last two options seems to provide us high flexibility.

**Still doubting about**

- Chosing one of the symfony solutions or Prestashop API's. Prestashop feels like a more complete solution, but I don't know if it will be as extendable as we want.
- If I pick the Symfony side I'm not sure about wich bundle use. Sylius have many more people using it but I think is more full stack solution. Otherwise, Aimeos Symfony bundle looks nice to me as well, their API doc is great. I can't find any Sylius vs Aimeos post (this is one of the mains reasons why I'm writting this question) that could help me to decide.

Having our requirements and experience into account what headless ecommerce you recommend us? Have you use any of our finalists just as a back end? Do you have any other recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Just found your question accidentally. I don't know if you are still interested (let me know if your project is already live or in development!), but Sylius does support your requirements.

We solve it via ShopApiPlugin: https://github.com/Sylius/ShopApiPlugin. It's still under development (lacking energy recently), but there's already a very nice and quite big shop working on it: https://shop.athletic-club.eus/. Our Partner has even developed a skeleton to improve working on it: https://github.com/LIN3S/ECommerce

In general I advice to read about our REST API: https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.3/api/introduction.html
https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.3/cookbook/api/api.html

And join our Slack - there are a lot of people who can help you there: sylius.com/slack

Cheers!

Comment: What is your affiliation with this project?  Please disclose.

Comment: Hi, the project has been delayed so thank you for your response! But I don't really get what's the ShopApiPlugin for. What provides to Sylius. I mean, I thought that Silius API already offered you ecommerce functionality.